# Neo4j - How do you do parallel insertion into a linked list via Cypher over REST?

Tags: rest, linked-list, neo4j, cypher

I want to create a linked list using Cypher over REST.

If I create the head of the list using the following query:

```
MERGE (headNode:HEAD {list:"mylist"})
WITH headNode
MERGE headNode-[:LINK]->(headNode)
RETURN headNode
```

And then do the insert using this query:

```
MERGE (headNode:HEAD {list:"mylist"})-[old:LINK]->after
DELETE old
CREATE headNode-[:LINK]->(newNode:LINKNODE { number : {nodeNumber} })-[:LINK]->after
```

Then everything is fine as long as I don't run multiple insert queries in parallel. But when I do I start to get consequences that are bad. I either get (depending on the timing) an error like:

```
Error: Relationship 391112 not found
```

Or I get multiple linked lists snaking out of the head node. I have set up a test node.js project that replicates the problem [here](https://github.com/aranm/neo4j-linked-list).

How does one create a linked list in Neo4j that can handle parallel insertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend not trying to second guessing how the locking works. Let's instead build something with the better-documented tools and features at our disposal.

Say we have a unique constraint like this:

```
create constraint on (n:LINK) assert n.list_head_id is unique
;
```

Then we can concurrently insert at the head of a list (potentially creating it in the process) like this:

```
merge (current_head:LINK {list_head_id: {list_id}})
on create set current_head.is_sentinel = true
remove current_head.list_head_id
create (new_head:LINK {list_head_id: {list_id}})-[:NEXT]->current_head
;
```

This kind of list always ends with a sentinel link, so you need to ignore that when you query it.

Now, the above can produce deadlock exceptions that will fail the transaction. Potentially a lot of them. So you need to make sure to retry those transactions that fail with deadlocks.

I wrote my own test in Java to demonstrate this approach. Note that in this test, I introduce a small random delay between transactions to reduce the probability of deadlocks. This is because the test is using an embedded database, so there’s no network or anything to otherwise limit the amount and speed of the concurrency I can throw at it: https://gist.github.com/chrisvest/9033600

Comment: Thanks Chris, much indebted to you for this answer.

Comment: @ChrisVest is it easy to turn this into a web api method?

Comment: @AranMulholland you can make it a procedure in 3.0.

Comment: @ChrisVest Do you reckon you could use this same procedure to make a circular linked list? :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to do parallel insert you need to take a lock on the node(s) in question:

```
MATCH (headNode:HEAD {list:"mylist"})-[old:LINK]->after
REMOVE headNode._lock_
REMOVE after._lock_
DELETE old
CREATE headNode-[:LINK]->(newNode:LINKNODE { number : {nodeNumber} })-[:LINK]->after
RETURN headNode, newNode
```

the lines

```
REMOVE headNode._lock_
REMOVE after._lock_
```

remove a non-existent property, when a property is removed a lock is taken. Now if the query can not insert due to the lock you will get a **Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure** which means the insert failed and you can re-run the query.

Comment: After further research I have found this approach does not work, the lock is not taken correctly

Comment: hi did you find any solution for that?

Comment: No sorry I didn't. It was incredibly irritating and I spent weeks on it. Have you tried the accepted answer? I don't remember marking it as such.

Comment: Not yet.. but I dont really like the idea of giving an id to a node by myself.. looks risky

Comment: It's not the actual node ID is it?

Comment: Dont think so.. it can be any generated id

Comment: I think he is just using it to guarantee uniqueness, should be cool.